# Adding more than one conditional in an <img> src?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is a line of code in my react app

`<img className='ArrowIcon' src={data?.quote_data[0].change < 0 && arrowdown}></img>`

I am trying to change the icon when the data is less than 0 and greater than 0 but dont know how to include both in the `src` of the `img`.

Is there any way to add in that when `data?.quote_data[0].change > 0` it returns `arrowup`. When I use a comma it gives and error.

Thanks :)

Comment: maybe `? :` if else (ternary operator) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the title of your question - you need a conditional expression, so use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
<img
  className='ArrowIcon'
  src={
    data?.quote_data[0].change < 0 ? arrowdown
    : data?.quote_data[0].change > 0 ? arrowup
    : defaultvalue
  }
></img>
```

(where `defaultvalue` would be if neither condition is fulfilled)